# transformToXml returns false but libxml_get_last_error() empty

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I am trying to transform an XML file using XSL in PHP. Both the XML and XSL files are loaded correctly from the local file system, but when I call:

```
$xslt->transformToXml($xml)
```

it returns `false`, yet both `libxml_get_last_error()` and `libxml_get_errors()` are empty.

Is there a way I can debug this or get some useful errors?

NB. My error_reporting is E_ALL | E_STRICT, display_errors is on.

Comment: I've been simplifying and working through my XSL file. It seems that `libxml_get_last_error()` and `libxml_get_errors()` return errors pretty inconsistently depending on the state of the file. Would be great if anyone could shed some light...